# How can I run a Unix script every hour, but after 4AM?

Tags: bash, date, unix

I would like to let a script run every hour, but only if its after 4AM. My current attempt:

```
if [ -e filename ] || [ date +%k%M < 400 ]
then don't do anything
else do something 
fi
```

I am assuming that at 4AM date +%k%M would show 400 or is it 0400? Is there a better way to check if 4AM has been passed?

Cheers

Edit: I'm not able to use cron jobs. The script will run 24/7 and should check if it is after or before 5AM.

Comment: In general you can use cron to schedule commands at a given time. I am not sure if there is a better way than specifying each hour you want the task to run, but you should take a look at it https://linux.die.net/man/8/cron

Comment: I am not able to use cron jobs. I will add this to my question.

Comment: Not sure if there is a better way but `+%k` will return 4 (no leading zero).  You can simplify a little by using `date +%k > 4`

Comment: are you absolutely sure that you cannot use `cron`? (i'm pretty sure you have good reasons - but normally everybody can; so are there any specific reasons why you have to avoid it?); could you use `systemd`?

Comment: I am 100% sure that I am not able to use cron. Thanks @JosefP. it works great. :)

Comment: I do agree with the previous comments though, it does sound like a scheduler would be more appropriate (assuming you've tried and can't use crontab -e for some reason?).  Plus I'd review your wording a little, it's a bit confusing.  Are you specifically wanting to run every hour from 5am-11am?  Your example code will run from 12am - 3am (i.e. <400)

Comment: Cron is not enabled on the server and I'm in no position to change that anytime soon sadly. The code shall run unless it is 0:00 - 4:00. I am using `date +%k -le 4`now so if the current hour is lesser than 4 it will not run.

Answer (score 1):

You could use just crontab to set hour limits:

```
1 4-18 * * * command
```

This executes "command" between 4 am and 6 pm, at the first minute of every hour.

Comment: As stated in my question, I'm not able to use cron jobs.

Comment: Ok. If your program runs 24/7 as you said, then you must build your own "cron". Your script must include an infinite loop, check time in every step of loop, and execute "if" section. Then, at the end of the loop step, you probably must insert some kind of delay or pause, that way your script will not eat all procesor resources.